# Method grouping other methods of the same family and how to call any of these separately

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, python, object-oriented-design

Worse title ever but I don't really know how to describe my scenario in a line...

So I have a method that wraps the calls of a many methods of the same nature. Once any of these methods have finished, a certain update needs to be called.

```
class SomeClass:
    def perform_tasks():
        self.task1()
        self.task2()
        self.task3()

    def task1(self):
        # perform task 1...
        # then update
        self.update()

    def task2(self):
        # perform task 2...
        # then update
        self.update()

    def task3(self):
        # perform task 3...
        # then update
        self.update()
```

Since `update` is called every time like that, I could refactor these calls:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = [self.task1, self.task2, self.task3)

    def perform_tasks():
        for task in self.tasks:
            task()
            self.update()
```

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that `SomeClass` can be inherited so that the tasks to perform may partially change.

However now I am in need of calling some individual tasks separately, and I still need the update to be performed after any of these tasks. What is some design that would let me do that without being repetitive at calling `update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a decorator to easily add `update` after each function::

```
from functools import wraps


def task(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.update()
    return wrapper


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = [self.task1, self.task2, self.task3]

    def perform_tasks(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            task()
            self.update()

    def update(self):
        print('updating')

    @task
    def task1(self):
        print('perfomring task 1')

    @task
    def task2(self):
        print('perfomring task 2')

    @task
    def task3(self):
        print('perfomring task 3')
```

You can also utilize the decorator to create the tasks list:

```
from functools import wraps


__next_task_idx = 0


def task(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.update()

    global __next_task_idx
    wrapper._task_idx = __next_task_idx
    __next_task_idx += 1
    return wrapper


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = [getattr(self, k)
                      for k, v in type(self).__dict__.items()
                      if hasattr(v, '_task_idx')]
        self.tasks.sort(key=lambda task: task._task_idx)

    def perform_tasks(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            task()

    def update(self):
        print('updating')

    @task
    def task1(self):
        print('perfomring task 1')

    @task
    def task2(self):
        print('perfomring task 2')

    @task
    def task3(self):
        print('perfomring task 3')
```

What's going on here? I've maked each task with `_task_idx` (incremental - so they'll be in order) and in the construct I've looked them up (in the type - they will not exist in the object's `__dict__` until called), collected them to a list, and sorted it (because the object's `__dict__` is unordered).

The advantage of this approach is that it couples adding a task to the list with making it call `self.update()`.